# how to set user agent for get_headers PHP function

Tags: php, curl, user-agent, get-headers

I know It's easy to set user agent for curl but my code is based on get_headers, by default get_headers user agent is empty.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming here, the best option (instead of a server-wide change, which who knows what might break), is to use [stream context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) (the [user agent option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.user-agent), in particular).

The PHP documentation already shows [an example for change the HTTP method](https://www.php.net/get_headers#example-3872) (sadly, also using a global setting ).

In any case, the code would be something like:

```php
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0'
    ]
]);

$headers = get_headers('http://example.com', true, $context);
```

Answer (score 1):

get_headers only specifies the data sent by the *server* to the *client* (in this case, PHP), it doesn't specify request headers.

If you're trying to find the user agent the get_headers request was made with, you'll have to use:

```
ini_get('user_agent');
```

For more documentation see the links below:

- https://www.php.net/get_headers
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent